# Highlight sums in excel column greater than a value

Tags: python, excel, pandas, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I have a sorted column and I want to hightlight those rows that when summed up less than a threshold value in this case 0.8. If you run this code below it will hightlight 0.294 and 0.202 but that only adds up to 0.496; I want it to also highlight 0.171, but not 0.157 as this would take it over 0.8

Am I using the right criteria in my conditional format?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([.294, .202, .171, .157, .103, .082, .045, .023, .021, .018, .016]))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('results.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
wb = writer.book
yellow_format = wb.add_format({'bg_color':'#F7FE2E'})

ws = writer.sheets['sheet1']
ws.conditional_format('A2:A20' , {'type': 'formula', 'criteria': '=SUM(A2:A20) >= 0.8', 'format':  yellow_format})

wb.close()
```

Comment: *when summed up less than a threshold*... but your formula is `>= 0.8`. So...is it lower or higher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first of all this answer is just Excel, because I do not know Pythong coding, but I hope that if you know how to make this in Excel, probably you can code it :)

You almost had it. You need the sum range to be dinamic. Your actual formula just checks if `A2:A20` sum is higher than 0,8. Because you are using relative references, when cheking `A2`, formula will sum up `A2:A20`, but when checking `A3` it will check `A3:A21`, and so on.

With the values provided, `SUM(A2:A20)` = 1.132, and because you typed  `>= 0.8` it highlights `0.294`. `SUM(A3:A21)=0.838` so `.202` gets highlighted too. But rest of sums don't sum up higher than 0.8.

So you need your conditional formatting rule to use this formula:

`=SUM($A$2:A2)<=0.8` Thay way, starting at row 2, it will hightlight the cells if the sum of row 2 until actual position is **lower** than 0.8. so at first value it will sum uo `A2:A2`, second value will sum up `A2:A3` and so on. Note I use absolute reference, but only on first cell, not the full range, so the range when dragging down is dynamic.

> [Switch between relative, absolute, and mixed
> references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Applying this conditional formattin rule based on this formula highlights exactly the values you said in your post.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the explanation, works perfectly, all it needed was  =SUM($A$2:A2)<=0.8 into the code.